# How to print all lines containing a number between 0 and 4 with decimals using shell script?

Tags: shell, unix, sed, scripting, output

So I have a file of some 500 lines, on every line there is a word followed by a number value. Format:

```
word number
word number
word number
```

and so on. All words have a decimal number next to it(with spaces in between) so 1.2493 or 6.2342 and so on. I want to output all lines that have a number between 0 and 4. How do I do this?

Note: my values range from 1 to 7 all number values are float values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assumed that the file contents is like below.

```
$ cat file
foo 1.2493
bar 6.2342
barfoo 3.675
```

AWk command would be,

```
$ awk '$2>0&&$2<4' file
foo 1.2493
barfoo 3.675
```

It prints the lines only if   the value of 2nd column must be greater than `0` and lesser  than `4`.

Comment: Good solution. And possibly use `>=` and `<=` as well depending on whether your ranges are inclusive or exclusive.

Comment: So then if I wanted all values from 5 to 7 I would do awk '$2>4&&$2<7'  ?? (btw thanks again!)

Comment: no, it would be `$2>=5&&$2<=7` if you want the values between 5 and 7 (`5` and `7` included).

Comment: @stuntstool [wait for some more time and accept the answer which really helped you.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)

Comment: OH ok, Thanks again. Sorry, I'm a total noob. But this saves me a ton of time in organizing my data for my thesis.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another approach, based on regular expressions. Using the same input file that Avinash Raj used in his `awk` solution:

```
$ grep -E ' ([0-3]\.|4\.0+$)' inp 
foo 1.2493
barfoo 3.675
```

This just looks for a space followed by a number where the number either (a) begins with 0 through 3 followed by a decimal point or (b) begins with 4, a decimal point, and one or more zeros followed by the end of the line.

Comment: Checked this out, out of curiosity and it did what I needed as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As you tagged your question "sed", here is my sed version for numbers >= 0 and < 4:

```
sed -n '/ [0-3]\./p' yourfile
```

and if you also want to allow 4.0 with an arbitrary number of zeros after the decimal dot:

```
sed -n '/ [0-3]\./p;/ 4\.0*$/p' yourfile
```